# select2 - limiting selection of one list based on value of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How do I do what this fiddle does in select2 (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6h5s/

html:

```
<select id="sel1">
<option value="1">Fruit</option>
<option value="2">Animal</option>
<option value="3">Bird</option>
<option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select id="sel2">
<option data-val="1">Banana</option>
<option data-val="1">Apple</option>
<option data-val="1">Orange</option>
<option data-val="2">Wolf</option>
<option data-val="2">Fox</option>
<option data-val="2">Bear</option>
<option data-val="3">Eagle</option>
<option data-val="3">Hawk</option>
<option data-val="4">BWM<option>
</select>
```

js:

```
$("#sel1").change(function() { 
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    $(this).data('options',$('#sel2 option').clone());
    } 
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-val=' + id + ']');
$('#sel2').html(options);
});
```

is it possible with built in functionality, or do I need to hook into

also, is it possible to select the right sel1 after a sel2 has been chosen?

Comment: The example provided uses jQuery to help in the selection, filtering and showing and hiding corresponding elements associated to what is selected on the 1st select. Do you want to do this in native JavaScript? Is that your question?

Comment: I'd like to use the select2 plugin, because it allows typing results into the fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing thoroughly, I realized that my previous example was destructive in filtering. It only allowed a one time filter, and then your options were gone. I've taken a few minutes to fix that problem.

HTML:

```
<select id="sel1">
    <option value="all">ALL</option>
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select id="sel2">
    <option data-val="1">Banana</option>
    <option data-val="1">Apple</option>
    <option data-val="1">Orange</option>
    <option data-val="2">Wolf</option>
    <option data-val="2">Fox</option>
    <option data-val="2">Bear</option>
    <option data-val="3">Eagle</option>
    <option data-val="3">Hawk</option>
    <option data-val="4">BMW</option>
</select>

<div class="cloned" style="margin-top: 2em;">
    <p>The data object in cache.</p>    
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var select = $('#sel2'),
    cache = $('#sel2').clone();
$('.cloned').append(cache);
$("#sel1").change(function() { 
    var id = $(this).val(),
        options = [];
    select.empty();
    cache.find('option').each(function () {
        if (id === 'all') {
            select.append($(this).clone());
        } else if ($(this).data('val') == id) {
            select.append($(this).clone());
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a working fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/SY47J/

Comment: Well this is a little embarrassing. I did not think the example fiddle was working when I visited that page so I forked it and rewrote it. Ah, maybe it will help someone. I'll delete it if anyone down-votes me.